# Creating a secure database for saving passwords on a password generator&saver on python

Tags: python

I am working on a code to generate, save and also retrieve previously saved passwords. The code has three functions which can generate, save and retrieve passwords.
In the code below, I have saved the passwords in a text file but I do not think this is secure so I am looking for a more secure way to save the passwords. Any suggestions?

```
from string import punctuation
from random import randint
from random import choice

strings = '''strange terrible chainlike convivial fan-leafed affordable popular fabulous irritating shiny comforted wonderful skillful average exceptionable arrogant\
 lazy biting wasteful respectful gorgeous vicious ferocious loving cheery orange illogical stoic vast comfortless great furry crease-resistant\
 reclusive artificial persistent slight closed-in crushing scary certifiable lithe hard content faint pretend poor famous impressionable\
 fervent small creative vivid hope helpful bloody heated up joyous painstaking fragile quickest self-assured sensitive slippery unassuming\
 emotional passive center swift volcanic reliable squeamish elated resonant scrawny deviant striped diplomatic sneaky misty believing\
 easy breeze'''

adjectives = strings.split(' ')
newadj = [word.capitalize() for word in adjectives]
main = choice(newadj)
number = randint (10,1000)
char = choice(punctuation)

def passwordgen():
    ''' Use this function when you want to generate a password without saving it.'''
    
    print('Hello Olaitan, welcome to your password picker!')
    

    password = main + str(number) + char
    print(f' Your password is {password}')
    return password

def passwordsave():
    '''Use this function if you want to create and store password and username for an app or website.'''
    
    print('Welcome to your password saver.')
    application = input('Enter the name of the application,website or name which the password is for:>> ')
    username = input('Enter your username:>>')
    passwords = passwordgen()
    new = input('Would you like to generate another passwrd for this app?\
\nEnter "y" or "n":')
    while new == 'y':
        passwords = passwordgen()    #there, the password gen function is called.
        new = input('Would you like to generate another passwrd for this app?\
\nEnter "y" or "n":')
    try:
        with open('passwordsaver.txt','a') as saver:
            saver.write(f'{application}>> Username: {username}; Password: {passwords}\n')
    except:
        with open('passwordsaver.txt','w') as saver:
            saver.write(f'{application}>> Username: {username}; Password: {passwords}\n')
    print(f'Your password: {passwords} and username: {username} for {application} has been saved.')
    
def passwordget():
    '''Use this function to retrieve password and username previusly saved.'''
    appname = input('Enter the name of the application or website:>>')
    info = []
    with open('passwordsaver.txt','r') as save:
        for line in save.readlines():
            if line.startswith(appname.capitalize()):
                info.append(line)
        if len(info) == 0:
            print('Application not found in database.')
        else:
            for data in info:
                print(data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your case, the number one concern is how you are storing the passwords.  You are correct, files in itself, but also coupled with not being encrypted, provides the most unsecure method in saving passwords.

To accomplish your task, I recommend the use of a secure database.  if your database is small, you can use SQL LITE which has the ability to save the SQLLITE file in an encrypted method and you can save your passwords there.  if there are millions of passwords, then you should move up to SQL SERVER or ORACLE.

To work SQL LITE, you can refer to this article: http://blog.dornea.nu/2011/07/28/howto-keep-your-passwords-safe-using-sqlite-and-sqlcipher/

in short, you build a sql lite table group to manage your passwords, and then employ the SQLLITE add-on SQLCYPHER.  this will encrypt the SQLLITE file.

Good luck.